# React Native how to render imgs in 5 col layout

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I'm building my first react-native app and am having trouble rendering images inside a 5 col layout built with flex. On web I would make the images responsive by giving them a width of 100% of their container and adding margin 0 auto. This doesn't work on react-native, so I'm wondering if their are different design principles for how to make react-native responsive for both mobile and tablet apps?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native';
import { Text, Container, Content, View } from 'native-base';

class Question extends Component {
    render() {
        const {
            widgetPredictor,
            widgetPredictor__text,
            widgetPredictor__imgs,
            widgetPredictor__heading,
            widgetPredictor__count,
            widgetPredictor__img__result,
            widgetPredictor__img__arrow,
            widgetPredictor__img__size
        } = styles;

        const { question, index, total, showPreviousQuestion, showNextQuestion } = this.props;

        return (
            <Container>
                <Container style={[widgetPredictor, widgetPredictor__text]}>
                    <Text style={widgetPredictor__heading}>{ question.label }</Text>
                    <Text style={widgetPredictor__count}>{ index + 1 } of { total }</Text>
                </Container>
                <Container style={[widgetPredictor, widgetPredictor__imgs]}>
                    <View style={widgetPredictor__img__arrow}>
                        <Image
                            style={widgetPredictor__img__size}
                            source={require('../../assets/imgs/left.png')}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={widgetPredictor__img__result}>
                        <Image
                            style={widgetPredictor__img__size}
                            source={require('../../assets/imgs/Huddersfield.png')}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={widgetPredictor__img__result}>
                        <Image
                            style={widgetPredictor__img__size}
                            source={require('../../assets/imgs/Draw.png')}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={widgetPredictor__img__result}>
                        <Image
                            style={widgetPredictor__img__size}
                            source={require('../../assets/imgs/Wednesday.png')}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={widgetPredictor__img__arrow}>
                        <Image
                            style={widgetPredictor__img__size}
                            source={require('../../assets/imgs/right.png')}
                        />
                    </View>
                </Container>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    widgetPredictor: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        height: 108
    },
    widgetPredictor__text: {
        backgroundColor: "red"
    },
    widgetPredictor__imgs: {
        backgroundColor: "blue"
    },
    widgetPredictor__heading: {
      color: "#141414",
      fontFamily: "Avenir",
      fontSize: 12,
      fontWeight: "500",
      marginBottom: 10,
        paddingLeft: "3%",
        paddingRight: "3%"
    },
    widgetPredictor__count: {
      color: "#C8D6DE",
      fontFamily: "Avenir",
      fontSize: 8,
      fontWeight: "900",
      marginBottom: 10,
        paddingLeft: "3%",
        paddingRight: "3%"
    },
    widgetPredictor__img__result: {
        borderRadius: 100,
        paddingLeft: "3%",
        paddingRight: "3%",
        flex: 2
    },
    widgetPredictor__img__arrow: {
        paddingLeft: "3%",
        paddingRight: "3%",
        flex: 1
    },
    widgetPredictor__img__size: {
        height: 70,
        width: 70
    }
};

export default Question;
```

I have only been able to render the whole imgs by specifying a height and width, I haven't been able to make them dynamically fill their containers. This is fine on tablet but the imgs overlap on mobile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`resizeMode='contain'`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#resizemode):

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    image: {
        flex: 1,
    }
});

render() {
    let mode = 'contain';
    return (
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', height: 100}}>
            <Image source={imageClose} resizeMode={mode} style={styles.image} />
            <Image source={imageClose} resizeMode={mode} style={styles.image} />
            <Image source={imageClose} resizeMode={mode} style={styles.image} />
            <Image source={imageClose} resizeMode={mode} style={styles.image} />
            <Image source={imageClose} resizeMode={mode} style={styles.image} />
            <Image source={imageClose} resizeMode={mode} style={styles.image} />
            <Image source={imageClose} resizeMode={mode} style={styles.image} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the required width/height of the images by using the [Dimensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html) element from react native to get the window width.

```
const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
const myImageWidth = width / 5;
```